# Can not compile HTML that Load From API Dynamically On Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an API that load Menu String Looks Like :

```
<li class="menu-title">
            <span>Menus</span>
          </li><ul><li class="submenu" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : urlComplete.mainUrl === 'users' }"  mCode="SYSTEM" >
   <a href="javascript:" [ngClass]="{ 'subdrop' : urlComplete.mainUrl === 'users' }"  class="">
       <i class='la la-windows'></i>
       <span>
           System
       </span>
       <span class="menu-arrow">
       </span>
   </a>
   <ul style="display: none;" [ngStyle]="{ 'display' : urlComplete.mainUrl === 'users' ? 'block' : 'none' }" class=""><li routerLink="/users/user/list" class="" mCode="USERS" >
   <a [ngClass]="{ 'active' : urlComplete.subUrl === 'user' }" href="javascript:" class="">
       Users
   </a>
</li><li routerLink="/users/user/create" class="" mCode="MENU" >
   <a [ngClass]="{ 'active' : urlComplete.subUrl === 'menu' }" href="javascript:" class="">
       Menus
   </a>
</li>   </ul>
</li>
</ul><li> <hr> </li>
```

I want to place this on Agular HTML page. Its shows fine but router link does not work. I understood that its not compile because of dynamic loading.
My front end code below :

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     this._getPermittedMenu();
  }



  _getPermittedMenu(){
    let apiURL = this.baseUrl + "/common/getAuthMenus";
    let queryParams: any = {};
    this.loginService.sendGetRequest(apiURL,queryParams).subscribe((response: any) => {
      // append response
      let unFormattedData  = response.data;
      let data  = unFormattedData.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");

      //compile string to html element and sanitize it
      this.menuData = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(data);



      // this.menuData =(this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(data));
      // console.log("REques menu data");
      // console.log(this.menuData);

    });

  }
```

and I m calling this from

```
  <div id="sidebar-menu" [innerHTML]="menuData"  class="sidebar-menu">
```

The problem is menus show but routerLink can not work link click

I provide some screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Angular won't recognize the string of HTML as Angular specific template code e.g. the `routerLink` will just be treated as a regular attribute not a directive

Comment: @Drenai How can I solve these issues.